# Excel CHISQ.TEST

Tags: chi-squared-test, excel

In Excel, if I get a value that is less than alpha (i.e. I get a value near zero) for the CHISQ.TEST function, does this mean that the my observed data follows the expected distribution or is it the other way around?

Answer (score 5):

[Microsoft says](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/chisq-test-function-HP010335674.aspx)

> `CHISQ.TEST` returns the probability that a value of the $\chi^2$ statistic at least as high as the value calculated by the above formula could have happened by chance under the assumption of independence.

This means that `CHISQ.TEST` is measuring the upper tail, and so a value near zero from `CHISQ.TEST` means that the $\chi^2$ statistic is relatively large, with the observed values not close to the expected values.  The older `CHITEST` was similar.

Answer (score 4):

The function `chisq.test` in Excel returns the p-value for a [chi-squared test of independence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test#Test_of_independence).

The p-value carries its [usual meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value) -

> In statistical significance testing, the p-value is the probability of obtaining a test statistic result at least as extreme as the one that was actually observed, assuming that the null hypothesis is true.

In the case of a chi-squared test of independence, it's the probability of obtaining a chi-squared statistic at least as large as the observed one, if the two categorical variables were independent.

Very low p-values therefore indicate that the data are inconsistent with independence in the population.